# Using maven quarkus:dev target, why would I get an unresolved dep on com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation

Tags: quarkus

A colleague posted a quarkus project to our internal git.  When I cloned the repo, and did 'mvn compile quarkus:dev', I get:

```
$ mvn compile quarkus:dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< com.fnorb.api:rest-cloudpoc >------------------
[INFO] Building rest-cloudpoc 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ rest-cloudpoc ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ rest-cloudpoc ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 30 source files to C:\Bitbucket\INT\java-rest-cloudpoc\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Bitbucket/INT/java-rest-cloudpoc/src/main/java/com/fnorb/api/rest/cloudpoc/beans/DeriveTemplate.java:[4,40] package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
```

The "fasterxml.jackson.annotation" line is repeated N times, capped at 100.

There are also instances of

```
[ERROR] /C:/Bitbucket/INT/java-rest-cloudpoc/src/main/java/com/fnorb/api/rest/cloudpoc/beans/ObjectType.java:[18,2] cannot find symbol
   symbol: class JsonInclude
```

The dep tree shows:

```
[INFO] +- io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-http:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
....
[INFO] |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-core:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.quarkus:quarkus-netty:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
....
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.vertx:vertx-core:jar:3.8.5:compile
....
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile
```

Is this just a misconfiguration of my host systems? Tried on Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04 headless (Linux subsystem for Windows) and Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS native.

Technology evidenced above (ie, like 'beans') of which I have added no commentary, assume I have no knowledge of that particular technology. If you think this is related to the problem -- great! but will need hand-holding if you need me to do something with them.  Don't just say "huh beans. You need to frog blast the vent core, the reticulator dependency hasn't been frinosticated yet" because I will just nod, rub my chin, shrug and try very hard not to tsk you.  Thanky.

**Please tell me I missed a step someplace!**

Edit 1:  Request for POM dependencies

```
  <version>0.1</version>
    <properties>
      <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
      <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
      <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <quarkus-plugin.version>1.4.2.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
      <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
      <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
      <quarkus.platform.version>1.4.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
      <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
          <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
          <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And request for imports in the imports from one of the relevant files:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
```

Comment: Can you add which dependencies are used in the POM file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no, your hosts are not misconfigured. Maven projects normally work out-of-the-box if they themselves are set up right.

First of all, the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` package is not in the `jackson-core` dependency but instead in the `jackson-annotations` package.

If you're using Quarkus, you'll get the `jackson-annotations` dependency indirectly if you're using ***for example*** `quarkus-smallrye-openapi`. But to me it seems like the class `DeriveTemplate` in your project imports something from `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation`, so the `jackson-annotations` should be declared as dependency directly in your `pom.xml`.

If this doesn't help you, you should post your `pom.xml` as well as the imports section of `DeriveTemplate` here.

Hope, I didn't *vent the frog capacitor* too much ;-)

Most likely, the missing dependency will look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations<artifactId>
    <version>${your-desired-jackson-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You called it -- The beans files all had jackson.annotation imports.  As an ask, could you please show the xml syntax for how to include the dependency in the pom?  I'm assuming it is something like ../dependency/groupid = jackson.annotation and ../dependency/artifactid = ... ? something.

Comment: It‘s as simple as putting the following snippet into your Pom.xml: <dependency><groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId><artifactId>jackson-annotations<artifactId><version>${your-desired-jackson-version}</version></dependency>  Find the latest or desired version at search.maven.org.

Comment: I copied the pom.xml example up into the answer.  Thank you!